# Supported wireless adaptors

Tags: wireless

Does anyone know if Ubuntu 12.04 LTS supports the following

1. Eidmax EW-7128g wireless PCI card
2. D-Link DWL-G122 USB adaptor
3. Belkin 802.11g USB adaptor (Model F5D7050uk)

Will they work out of the box or will I need drivers.  If so where can I get the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

To know whether they work weh would have to try it. You'll have to try yourself by booting Ubuntu from DVD or USB stick and see whether these devices work properly.

If they don't, you may likely find drivers on the manufacturer's website.